# Short comic book story about pets remaining after a human apocalypse occurs

Tags: story-identification, comics, post-apocalyptic, animals

A friend of mine is trying to find an old Hungarian story, here’s how they describe it:

“I remember a few characters, three of the main characters were;

- A white cat with a purple bow/collar, female
- A male pug-looking dog
- A pigeon

Some minor characters I remember: Some weasel I think, a cow, a boar

The story started with the pets talking about something in the daytime, then went on with them going in the dog’s owners abandoned House when it got dark (since humans disappeared in the story) and they tried to find food. Then the cow somehow broke in the house, the weasel though it was a good idea to drink cow milk.
Later the boar came in causing chaos, and that's all I remember.”

If it helps, the Hungarian title is believed to be called “Az ötösfogat” but so many books fall under this title :( The art style is also a little more on the cartoon-y side rather than realistic.

Comment: Can you translate "az ötösfogat" to English? Google Translate thinks it's "the five teeth" but I don't believe it. (How come Google AIs can beat grandmasters at chess, and can purportedly drive cars on the road, but they are such lousy translators?)